# Question about determinant of a block matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, block-matrices

I was studying block matrices and suddenly this question came to my mind.

Let $A, B \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$. From this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices),

$$\det \begin{pmatrix} A & B\\ B & A\end{pmatrix} = \det(A-B)\det(A+B)$$

even if $A$ and $B$ do not commute. Does a similar condition hold for the following block matrix?

$$\begin{pmatrix}
A & -B\\ 
B & A
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $\det \left( \begin{smallmatrix} A & -B \\ B & A \end{smallmatrix} \right) =|\det(A+iB)|^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725852/proving-det-left-beginsmallmatrix-a-b-b-a-endsmallmatrix-righ)

Comment: @MartinR Thank you!
I also found this post : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486430/proof-for-determinant-of-a-block-matrix

These two posts answer my question.

Comment: @saulspatz That's the same post with my comment but thank you.

Comment: @TUC My comment was automatically generated by the site when I voted to close the question as a duplicate.  Actually, it was your comment that led me to the page.