# If $A=B+iC$ is Hermitian, are eigenvalues of $A$ also eigenvalues of $\begin{pmatrix}B&-C\\C&B\end{pmatrix}$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, hermitian-matrices

Suppose $A$ is a complex Hermitian matrix which then can be expressed as

$A = B + iC$
for $B$ and $C$ are real matrix.

I have proved that $A$ is Hermitian iff the following matrix $M$ is symmetric:

$$
M =
\begin{pmatrix}
 B & -C\\
C & B
\end{pmatrix}
$$

let $\lambda $ be an eigenvalue of $A$ then is $\lambda$ also an eigenvalue of $M$?

My first approach was the following:

since I proved that $M$ is symmetric and wants to show that the eigenvalue of $A$ is also an eigenvalue of $M$, I got some ideas from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486430/proof-for-determinant-of-a-block-matrix) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725852/proving-det-left-beginsmallmatrix-a-b-b-a-endsmallmatrix-righ).

Since the $det(M) = |det(B+iC)|^2 = |det(A)|^2$ and we also know that the determinant is a product of eigenvalues,

$det(A) = \lambda \Delta$, (where $\Delta$ is the product of all the eigenvalues of $A$ except $\lambda$)

$\lambda$ has to involve in the $det(M)$. But since $det(M) = |det(A)|^2$, I think it will have $\lambda ^2$ instead of $\lambda$.

I am kind of stuck here and my mind is tunneled right now. Is this whole process wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps $det(M) = det(A) \times det(A) = \lambda^2 \Delta^2= \lambda \Delta \lambda \Delta$ hence $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of M. Does this make sense? I am uncertain whether the $\lambda$ exists as an eigenvalue of $M$, not as $\lambda^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $\phi:M_n(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$, mapping $X+iY$ to $$
\begin{bmatrix}
X & -Y\\
Y & X
\end{bmatrix}
$$ has the property that for a complex vector $z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}^n$, we have $$
Mz = \tilde{x}+i\tilde{y}
$$ where $$
\phi(M)\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\tilde{x}\\
\tilde{y}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$ So if $\lambda$ is a **real** eigenvalue of $M$, then it is an eigenvalue of $\phi(M)$, too.

Edit: To understand what happens to eigenvalues under this map, it is enough to evaluate it on diagonal matrices. If $M=diag(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$, then there is a $2\times 2$-block in $\phi(M)$ for each $\lambda_i$: If $\lambda_i$ is real, then it is $\lambda_i I_2$. If $\lambda_i=x+iy$ is complex, then the block is $$
\begin{bmatrix}
x & -y\\
y & x
\end{bmatrix}
$$ and this $2\times 2$-matrix has characteristic polynomial $t^2-2tx+x^2+y^2$. Since $y\neq 0$, it has no real roots for any $x,y$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm getting kind of confused with $M = diag(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n)$. Is this M a new matrix or is it the same as the one above, i.e. $\begin{pmatrix}
B & -C\\ 
C & B
\end{pmatrix}$

sorry about typo

Comment: @TUC I just restricted the map $\phi$ to diagonal matrices as it gives us all the information about the eigenvalues we need. So $M=B+iC$ is again a complex matrix, just a diagonal one.

Comment: I think I just confused myself with the changed variables. In your answer, M is just $M = X + iY$ and $\phi(M) = \begin{bmatrix}
X & -Y\\ 
Y & X
\end{bmatrix}$ ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I have one last question: In the line $Mz = \overline{x} + i\overline{y}$, are $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{y}$ some new values and the overline is just to denote that they are different from $x$ and $y$? I learned $\overline{x}$ is the conjugate of $x$ in complex numbers. I guess this has nothing to do with it but I'd like to understand this thoroughly. Thank you

Comment: @TUC the notation is $\tilde$, not $\bar$, i.e., it is not complex conjugate just some other vectors. I could have used $a,b$ or $\alpha,\beta$ instead of $\tilde{x},\tilde{y}$.

Comment: Wow. again, thank you for all the answers / replies. Have a great day!

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you may consider to accept it so it does not look like an unanswered question.